# Swift: Add UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator and link to another tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have two tables in a tableview in one UIViewController(Not UITableViewController). Now I want to let only one of the cells adding UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator to let users click for viewing another tableview.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = UITableViewCell()
    if indexPath.section == 0{
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(rentTitle[indexPath.row]): \(rentArray[indexPath.row])"
    }else{
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(cashflowTitle[indexPath.row]): \(cashflowArray[indexPath.row])"
    }
    return cell
}
```

There are 6 rows in the first table and 5 rows in the second one. I want to add the disclosureIndicator in the third row of the second table. So the questions are: 1. How to add the disclosureIndicator in the 3rd row of the second table? 2. How to make that row actively link to another tableView? Thanks a lot!

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView,accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    var cell = UITableViewCell()
    if indexPath.section == 1{
        if indexPath.row == 2{
            print(indexPath.row)
        }
    }
}
```

I tried the print first.

Answer (score 0):

That arrow isn't a UINavigationItem; it's a UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator.

To add that UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator "arrow" to your cell's accessory view, add this line:

```
if indexPath.row == 2 { //Third row
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator
}
```

And then to perform a specific action when that accessory view is tapped, implement

> tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:

In this method implement your navigation by checking the indexPath again.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I solved the Indicator already. But how to add the action in the "tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:"?

Comment: This is a delegate method similar to `cellForRowAtIndex`. Implement the tap button in the same way.

Comment: I use UIViewController not UITableViewController. So the storyboard might be a little different, there is no "prototype cells" in the UIViewController. I tried "var cell" and check the indexPath again but doesn't work.